# Bash shell script Fahrenheit to Celsius error

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to use a shell script from someone else that makes a table of Fahrenheit values and the Celsius equivalent. I keep getting an error on line ten that says:

line 10:[1: command not found

I don't understand what the -lt part of the while statement is so I don't know how to modify it. The scripts accept the 3 inputs from the user then spits out that error mentioned above. Any help would be much appreciated.

here is the code for the script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter starting Fahrenheit temperature:"

read sf

echo "Enter end Fahrenheit temperature:"

red ef

echo "Enter the step increment:"

read step

echo "Fahrenheit Celsius"

while [ $sf -lt ef ]

do

     c=`expr ($sf-32)*5/9

     echo "$sf $c"

     sf=`expr $sf+$step

done
```

Comment: This question is not appropriate here. This is not a site for *I found this code somewhere else, but it doesn't work. Can someone here fix it for me?* questions. This isn't a code writing service, and we're not personal debuggers. Find a tutorial on bash scripting and make an effort to solve the problem yourself. If you're not willing to put in that effort, hire someone to do the work for you. Good luck.

Comment: Paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: The error you report is a common one but nothing in your script seems to contain exactly that. Line 10 appears to be empty, but there does seem to be a typo on line 9 (`red` pro `read`). Maybe see also [the Stack Overflow `bash` tag info](/tags/bash/info) but I too second the suggestion to try http://shellcheck.net/ and using a language which has more than just integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 3):

Bash can only handle integers, even with intermediate results and comparisons. Accordingly, the calculated and output values are incorrect.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i c sf   # set integer attribute

read -p "Enter starting Fahrenheit temperature:" sf
read -p "Enter end Fahrenheit temperature:" ef
read -p "Enter the step increment:" step

echo "Fahrenheit Celsius"

while [ $sf -lt $ef ]; do
     c=($sf-32)*5/9
     echo "$sf $c"
     sf=$sf+$step
done
```

Example:

```
echo "10
100
10" | ./script.sh
Fahrenheit Celsius
10 -12
20 -6
30 -1
40 4
50 10
60 15
70 21
80 26
90 32
```

I suggest to use Perl or Python for this task.

Comment: Nit pick: isn't it better to put `sf`, `ef`, and `step` in double quotes?